# Clojure version of Behat?

Tags: php, clojure, cucumber, behat

In the past, for PHP project's, I have used Behat in conjunction with the [api-extension](https://behat-api-extension.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to write component level tests. Behat shares a common philosophies with cucumber. I would therefore like to known if there is an equivalent api extension I could use for cucumber in a Clojure project?

This is the kind of test I would like to create:

```
Feature: MyFeature
Scenario: do somthing
      Given the request body is:
      """
      {
        "key": "val"
      }
      """
      And the "Content-Type" request header is "application/json"
      When I request "/route" using HTTP POST
      Then the response code is 200
      Then the response body contains JSON:
      """
      {
          "meta": {
              "status": "@variableType(string)"
          },
          "data": {
              "key": "@variableType(integer)"
          }
      }
      """
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=clojure+cucumber&oq=clojure+cucumber&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3648j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I wasn't able to find any library which supported similar step_definitions, hence why I posted this question.

Comment: Behat is a PHP-specific framework, you will likely not find an exact replica in any other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I *think* what you are looking for is a BDD framework that implements Gherkin in some way (as Behat does). The Cucumber framework, which you mention, does just that, and there exists a Clojure implementation which you can see here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-clojure

I think this is basically what you are looking for.